# Can't get an answer from Matlabs solve function

Tags: matlab, math, equation, solver, trigonometry

When I try to use solve with my predefine functions and vectors I get the following error message:

> Warning: Explicit solution could not be found.
>   In solve at 169
>   In cardanAngles at 33

I have three unknown variables and three equations. I should be able to find this answer. What could be wrong?

```
V0 = transpose([-0.7969, 0.1778, 0.5774]);
V = [-0.7976  ,  0.2282  ,  0.5583];

syms a1 a2 a3 


F1 = [ cos(a3 * pi / 180).*cos(a2 * pi / 180),  cos(a3 * pi / 180).*sin(a2 * pi / 180).*sin(a1 * pi / 180)+sin(a3 * pi / 180).*cos(a1 * pi / 180), -cos(a3 * pi / 180).*sin(a2 * pi / 180).*cos(a1 * pi / 180)+sin(a3 * pi / 180).*sin(a1 * pi / 180)];
F2 = [-sin(a3 * pi / 180).*cos(a2 * pi / 180), -sin(a3 * pi / 180).*sin(a2 * pi / 180).*sin(a1 * pi / 180)+cos(a3 * pi / 180).*cos(a1 * pi / 180),  sin(a3 * pi / 180).*sin(a2 * pi / 180).*cos(a1 * pi / 180)+cos(a3 * pi / 180).*sin(a1 * pi / 180)];
F3 = [ sin(a2 * pi / 180)                    , -cos(a2 * pi / 180).*sin(a1 * pi / 180)                                                           ,  cos(a2 * pi / 180).*cos(a1 * pi / 180)                                                           ];


[a1, a2,a3] = solve(V(1)==F1*V0,V(2)==F2*V0, V(3)==F3*V0, a1,a1,a3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a solution you can start by solving the last eq. that is, `F3*V0-V(3)=0`.
The eq reads:

```
F3 = [sin(a2), -cos(a2).*sin(a1),  cos(a2).*cos(a1)]; 
V0 = [-0.7969, 0.1778, 0.5774]';

F=V0(1)*sin(a2) - V0(2)*cos(a2)*sin(a1) + V0(3)*cos(a1)*cos(a2) - V(3);
```

We now need to look for a family of solutions where `F=0` at some place, a quick analysis will yield this:

[image]

Now you can use these as intial guess values for an  `fsolve` procedure as suggested in the comments. You can massage a bit the original form and write the following function:

```
function F = qfun(x)

V0 = transpose([-0.7969, 0.1778, 0.5774]);
V = [-0.7976  ,  0.2282  ,  0.5583];
F1 = [ cos(x(3) ).*cos(x(2) ),  cos(x(3) ).*sin(x(2) ).*sin(x(1) )+sin(x(3) ).*cos(x(1) ), -cos(x(3) ).*sin(x(2) ).*cos(x(1) )+sin(x(3) ).*sin(x(1) )];
F2 = [-sin(x(3) ).*cos(x(2) ), -sin(x(3) ).*sin(x(2) ).*sin(x(1) )+cos(x(3) ).*cos(x(1) ),  sin(x(3) ).*sin(x(2) ).*cos(x(1) )+cos(x(3) ).*sin(x(1) )];
F3 = [ sin(x(2) )                    , -cos(x(2) ).*sin(x(1) )                                                           ,  cos(x(2) ).*cos(x(1) )                                                           ];
F=(F1*V0-V(1))+abs(F2*V0-V(2))+abs(F3*V0-V(3));
```

and then on a separate file run something like:

```
options = optimset('Display','off');
for ...
x0 = [a1_found a2_found 0]; % guess values
[x,Fval,exitflag] = fsolve(@qfun,x0,options);
end...
```

each guess value vector will output the nearest solution, so loop with a good sampling of  your angle values to get `a3`.

Comment: Bare in mind that I havent programmed a lot in my days

In the function F is a value that is suppose to be equal to 0 if the guess vector guessed the it right.

in the second part. Could you explain the parts of the code? Is the for-loop suppose to change the guesses or what

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the a variant of the `qfun` to get values of `a1` and `a2` that satisfy `abs(F3*V0-V(3))=0`, by omitting the lines of F1,F2, and editing `F=abs(F3*V0-V(3))` . to get them you can use the separate file mentioned and loop over angles with decent sampling. Each pair of guess values for a1,a2 will converge to a close solution, and you'll get the plot I attached. Then use the obtained a1,a2 as guess values for the loop over a3 values.